# How to parse dynamic response using QtSoap?

Tags: qt

I have currently the response of type:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"><soap:Body><StartBuisnessResponse xmlns=\"http://test.com/kerosene/mytest/\"><StartBuisnessResult><Commodity><_price>45</_price></Commodity><Commodity><_price>36</_price></Commodity></StartBuisnessResult></StartBuisnessResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Here, the  node is dynamic. In such a case, I am not able to find a way to parse the response SOAP XML using QtSoap.

This is the Code which works for fetching the first commodity:

```
QString str("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"><soap:Body><StartBuisnessResponse xmlns=\"http://cg.nic.in/kerosene/finotest/\"><StartBuisnessResult><Commodity><_price>45</_price></Commodity><Commodity><_price>36</_price></Commodity></StartBuisnessResult></StartBuisnessResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>");

    QByteArray *arr = new QByteArray();
    arr->append(str);

    QtSoapMessage *testMsg = new QtSoapMessage();
    testMsg->setContent(*arr);

    const QtSoapType &testCont = testMsg->returnValue();
    const QtSoapType &price = testCont["Commodity"];

    qDebug() << "The value of the _price here is " << price["_price"].value().toString();
```

But how do I traverse through the subsequent  nodes in this case? Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the example shown on Qt Solutions `QtSoap` that they have for Google, you should be on your way with it.

http://doc.qt.digia.com/solutions/4/qtsoap/index.html

http://doc.qt.digia.com/solutions/4/qtsoap/google-example.html

An alternative if you don't want to try that is to use the QXmlStreamReader:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qxmlstreamreader.html#details

Here is some quick code to get out the `_price` information from this:

```
// add "QT += xml" to your .pro

#include <QXmlStreamReader>
#include <QDebug>

QXmlStreamReader xml(str);

while (!xml.atEnd())
{
    if (xml.readNextStartElement())
        qDebug() << qPrintable(xml.name().toString());
    if(xml.name().toString() == "_price")
    {
        qDebug() << "\t" << xml.readElementText().toInt();
    }
}
```

You also have a number of other alternatives available, too.  See [Qt XML Processing](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/xml-processing.html).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I did go through the google example. The situation is not exactly the same in this case. Since, subsequent tags after first <Commodity></Commodity> would look the same, QtSoapType always returns the first value. Looks like there is no way we can traverse further for the next <Commodity></Commodity> in this case. Am I right?

Comment: Besides testCont["name"], there is also testCont[index], as shown here: http://doc.qt.digia.com/solutions/4/qtsoap/qtsoaptype.html#operator-5b-5d So you can pass in integers until you find the element you want instead of just doing a map look up by name.